# angular reload the resolve when same route click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using bellow code to `reload` the `route` but it does `reload` only the view. i have a `resolve` object defined in my routes definitions file. How could i reload the route with `resolve` ?

```
$rootScope.changeRoute = function(){
  var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
  $templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
  $route.reload();
};
```

route.js

```
.when('/invoice/', {
    title: 'invoice',
    templateUrl: 'views/invoice/index.html',
    controller: 'invoiceController',
    resolve: {
            getInvoices: function (getInvoicesService, getDashbordService, dataService, $q, $rootScope) {

               var invoices  = getInvoicesService;
               var userDefaults  = getDashbordService || dataService.get();

               return $q.all([invoices, userDefaults]).then(function(results){

                 userDefaults.then(function(data){
                    $rootScope.menus = data.user_menu;
                 });

                  return {
                     'data' : results[0],
                     'defaults' : results[1]
                  };
    })
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: I don't think using `ngRoute` you can without full page reload. What is use case? Perhaps you can have a data refresh method in your service

Comment: how does angular handle this behaviours ?

Comment: Do what specifically?

Comment: I have a set off menu and every menu href's set to a route. And i just want to add data from menu m1 and i need those data available to the menu m2. But for the first time angular route it with the resolve. But when i again need to repeat above scenario angular does not reload the resolve.

Comment: Suggest you provide more code for this menu service and resolve. Sounds like you need to share data differently. Question sounds like an XY Problem

Comment: i just updated it with one route definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104439/discussion-between-underscore-and-charlietfl).